# How to see list of plugins

Tags: plugins, performance, debug

Is there any tool out there for seeing a list of all the loaded plugins and how much time they took to load? Looking to analyze plugins effect on my site's performance.

Comment: You can make use of a plugin called [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/)

Comment: [P3 Profiler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) is also good plugin to review site's performance

Comment: You may want to check out [WP Performance Profiler](https://wpperformanceprofiler.interconnectit.com/) for this. It is similar to P3 Performance Profiler in that it detects the amount of resources required for a specific plugin on your Wordpress installation, however it goes more in-depth than P3. It is also a good tool if you are a plugin developer and wanting to run load tests on your plugin.

Comment: As an aside comment for lack of points; Another approach, dare I say, a plugin with more fine grained results is [Query monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) which will not only show where plugins, themes slow down, but which queries are problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## There are a lot of tools available

Below are my personal favourites

1. Pingdom

   http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt
2. Google Pagespeed

   https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights
3. GTMetrix

   gtmetrix.com

Answer (score 3):

Daniel, it appears you're focused on the specific challenge of profiling plugins installed at the same time on a WP install, which doesn't appear addressed in the other answers so I thought I would chime in.

At Comit Developers, we've had a lot of success with [P3 - Plugin Performance Profiler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/).  I also like a lot when I'm just working on stuff on my own laptop, but moistly I'm worried about my own custom plugins when doing that and I find if you just need to analyze a single plugin, Z-Ray is usually faster...

I will confess we've become a bit spoiled with Z-Ray and P3 isn't quite there yet, though it's a very solid WP Plugin with a strong feature and bug fix release schedule history ([official GitHub mirror](https://github.com/wp-plugins/p3-profiler)) and that's not something you see in a lot of WP Plugins.

***Some of the things we like:***

1. **First Page is Immediately Helpful and Easy to View:** You do get a pretty easy to read overview with Runtime by Plugin, Number of Queries, Total Plugins all easy to note at a glance:

[image: P3 Performance Profile Report Overview]

2. **Detailed Timeline Shows Time-Load Ratio of All Plugins:** The detailed timeline is a really easy way to see each plugin's load time relative to the others and is also pretty easy for even non-technical users to grasp - great for explaining why a particular plugin might be better versus another to a client without diving deep into technical details.

[image: P3 Performance Profile Report Detailed Timeline]

3. **Works on WP Multi-Site:** This may not be a big deal to all users but it sure helps us in certain cases since those deployments can have plugin combinations effecting performance in different ways than on the single site deploys.
4. **Go Daddy is a Project Contributor & other Contributors provide an active community / contributor support forum:** Commercial backing does help to ensure that there's a consistent response to new issues as well as frequent releases that address issues and add features.  The [support forums show very active responses](https://github.com/wp-plugins/p3-profiler) to user questions both from contributors and community participants and the [reviews section seems to bear this out](https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/p3-profiler).
5. **It doesn't conflict with many (if any) plugins:**  Our WordPress Multi-Site shared hosting environment leverages all [140+ of the plugins from our partnership with WPMUDev](https://premium.wpmudev.org/) and a few others we like and that follow as many best practices as possible and so far, this has worked pretty well with all of them.  That being said, we love WPMUDev specifically for the quality of their code (consistently top notch and well documented and supported) so you may find other plugins may not play as nicely.  I'd say that any plugin that conflicts with this one may be not worth keeping though...

***Potential Drawbacks:***

**1. Native support for manual WP Plugin Installation method only:**  Not really a deal breaker for most since few WP plugins have native support for Composer or any other system like that.  This is easily manageable with [Bedrock Plugin Control](https://github.com/lamosty/bedrock-plugin-control).  Frankly. there are enough other advantages to using [Bedrock from roots.io](https://roots.io/bedrock/) for enabling a [12 Factor WP Platform](https://roots.io/twelve-factor-wordpress/) that it's probably worth using anyway and [WPGear](http://wpgear.org/) has even more options listed.  I did notice there a was an absence of [my favorite IDE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio) on WPGear, perhaps we see about getting it listed?  Another thread, of course ;)

**2. Issues with SOME Advanced PHP Feature Support Reported:** We haven't seen this particularly on ZS7 or ZS 8, but some users on the [HGV GitHub Issues list have reported issues with OpCode caching and this plugin with HHVM](https://github.com/wpengine/hgv/issues/43), so there's a chance at least that you may have to tweak some of the settings if using Optimizer+ or perhaps if running older php runtimes that are using apc.

**3. Static Low-Interactivity Reports:** The reports are well laid out for both technical and non-technical users, but they're basically static images and summaries and not dynamic nor do they offer in-depth technical features like drilling down into compositional sources of the data.

None of the drawbacks are really deal-breakers in my opinion though others may disagree.

We've been using the WordPress Z-Ray Extension for Zend Server more and more each day and although I was kidding (sort of) about becoming spoiled, I have noticed every dev on our team has raised the bar for what we consider good reporting and debugging plugins...P3 is better than anything else I've seen and surely better than using Chrome Devtool or Firebug in a browser, but we'd be more interested in a way t enhance the WP Z-Ray Extension to add in support for multi-plugin profiling.  See you on GitHub!